# How to merge a multiple text delimitted file in to a single file

Tags: cmd.exe

I have a lots of text delimited files and I want to merge them all in to a single file. In the mean time I don't want to have the first 4 lines in each files so I want to skip those lines and then merge them all in  DOS command. I have tried this command

```
for  %f in (*.OUT) do type "%f" >> output.OUT
```

It works in merging the file - however I want to add a command that would skip the first four lines in each file. Any help is appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would use `more` instead of `type`, with `+n` option to start reading each file at line n+1  (so line 5 in your case to skip the first 4 lines) :

```
for %f in (*.OUT) do more +4 "%f" >> output.OUT
```